# How to publish ASP.NET MVC site with File Zilla using FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, filezilla

I made an account to a Web Hosting site which only allows transfers & uploads using FTP. So, I tried hard to figure it out how to publish my Site with FTP. I tried Visual studio Publish but It didn't work. Now I want to upload it manually using File Zilla. Does anyone know which folders to upload from my Solution (Project). There are lots of so i am confused. If you can also explain about SQL Server setup. I would be highly grateful to you.

Comment: Publish it on your local file system and then copy that all using your ftp

Comment: Can you please explain. All of the files in Project?

Comment: First of all, do you know how to publish it on your local ?

Comment: No.. I would be grateful if you can explain :)

Comment: Were you able to get it up? How did you make the requests point to your app? I mean how did you replace the default index page that the web hosting providers have?

Comment: @stylojack_10 hosting provider automatically removed their page idk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open your project in Visual studio. Right click on your main project and click publish
2. Create a new profile with any name.Click next.
3. Select publish method as File System.
4. Also Select the location where you want to save.Click next.
5. Select Configuration as Release-Any CPU.
6. Click Publish.

Now you have published it on the location provided by you in 4th step.

Copy all the files from this location and upload it using FTP to the directory of your website where you want to.

For more information. Visit this link [How to Publish](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1286/how-do-i-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-discountasp_net-server.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Publish your source code to local file system.

> Right click on your App project and select Publish.
>
> You will see Publish Web wizard.
>
> In Profile tab -> Select New Profile from `DropDownList` and give profile name.
>
> Next is Connection tab -> Select File System from Publish Method DropDownList.
>
> Give path as Target Location where you would like to publish your source code.

[image: Screen Shot sample]

2. From file zilla do copy paste / selection to upload.

Comment: After I publish it to my own computer can I run it from there or do I have to put it up on my server before I can run it outside of visual studio?